# Why I cant go to next page after I select some of these checkboxes?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have an html table with bootstrap styling, and in the right side I have checkboxes in each row, but when I select them and click 'Write Report' button it doesn't go to next page, it doesn't do anything as if I didn't click anywhere. 
I am new to all this HTML, Bootstrap and PHP so probably there is a stupid mistake I am making somewhere.

Here is my table:

```
 <table id="usetTable" class="display compact" data-toggle="table" data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed" data-row-style="rowColors" data-striped="true" data-sort-name="Quality" data-sort-order="desc" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true">

        <thead>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true">Dev.no</th>
            <th>IMEI</th>
            <th>Report comment</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <form method="post">
                <?php if (!empty($devices)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach ($devices as $device) : ?>
                        <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">

                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="devices[<?php echo $device["id"] ?>]" value="<?php echo $device["id"] . $dev_comment ?>">
                                <?php echo $device["device_no"] ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $device["serial_imei"] ?>
                            </td>  

                            <td>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <textarea name="dev_comment[<?php echo $device["id"] ?>]" placeholder="comment" rows="1" cols="50"><?php echo $dev_comment; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </br>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="report">Write report</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#usetTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

I tried to post only the minimal code to reproduce this error even though I am using dynamic data so its kinda difficult to reproduce this way but in case you want to do that, just user hardcoded data in the table and remove the array fields.

P.S. the table is looking perfectly fine, the only problem is with selecting the rows and going to next page.
[Here is a screenshot][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IidBA.png

**EDIT:**
I am using jQuery function now and it works but the table lost pagination:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#usetTable').DataTable();
        $(function() {
        //Assign Click event to Button.
        $("#btnGet").click(function() {
            //Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in GridView.
            $("#usetTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
            });
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

if I remove this: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"
the table looks good but checkboxes dont work anymore.

Comment: you need to add action attribute in the form tag

Comment: @Mahesh `action=""` what should be inside action attribute?

Comment: The page which you want to redirect to after click of submit button

Comment: @Mahesh I really dont think the problem is there. If I add an empty <th> tag in <thead> it works, but like it is now it doesn't.

Comment: @Mahesh moreover I dont want to redirect immediately ,I first doing something in PHP code when submit is triggered

Comment: @Mahesh please help!

Comment: If you leave action="" empty it will post on this same page, and then you set php if isset and do what ever you want what you want in php.

Comment: You can use header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); to redirect to the page you desired after you perform action in php

Comment: @ikiK I tried with that empty attribute but nothing really changed. stil the same problem.

Comment: @Mahesh I am already doing that, however, I cant get the values of those checkboxes with the code I have.

Comment: After calculating things you can redirect using the header it would redirect once your things are done processing

Comment: @Mahesh I said I am already doing that, I can re direct properly. My problem is with checkboxes, I just cant take their values when submitting. However, I have edited the code, I am using jQuery now and they work BUT the table looks bad now. Please check the edited code.

Comment: If it is so you can use the jQuery to fetch the checkbox value and pass to the php variable that would be good choice

Comment: @Mahesh I am doing it now but the table lost pagination! How can I add pagination again?!